# Mysql sum with more then one table

Tags: mysql

I have first large table with some statistics, second Demand table and Third Supply table.

I have to show statistics. Sometimes i need to group it with some parameters (demand_tag_id, supply_tag_id, domain_id etc.)

There are 10 millions rows in the statistic's table.

This is my SQL Request;

```
SELECT 
s.requests,s.impression,s.bad_requests,s.empty_body,s.bad_vast,s.exceptions,s.midpoint,s.complete,s.click,
    (s.impression / s.requests) * 100 as req_fill,
    (s.click / s.impression) * 100 as ctr,(s.complete / s.impression) * 100 as completion,
    s.media_cost,s.revenue 
    FROM ( 
        SELECT SUM(t.requests) AS requests, SUM(t.impression) AS impression, SUM(t.bad_requests) AS bad_requests, SUM(t.empty_body) AS empty_body, SUM(t.bad_vast) AS bad_vast, SUM(t.exceptions) AS exceptions, SUM(t.midpoint) AS midpoint, SUM(t.complete) AS complete, SUM(t.click) AS click, 
        SUM(IF(p.rate_type = "0", (t.impression * p.fixed_rate) / 1000, (t.impression * d.rate) / 1000 * (p.percent_rate / 100))) as media_cost, 
        SUM((t.impression * d.rate) / 1000) as revenue 
        FROM 7days_Stats t 
        JOIN Demands d ON d.id = t.demand_tag_id 
        JOIN Supplies p ON p.id = t.supply_tag_id
    ) s
```

This request need 38 seconds.

But if i remove JOIN, revenue and media_cost from this request, it need 11 seconds.

How i can to do this request faster? Please help me!

Comment: Thought about indexes?

Comment: 11 seconds is not a good solution either. What kind of indexes, primary keys and foreign keys do you have on your table? can we see the schema of the table and the explain of your query?

Comment: all these fields which i used in query are indexes. Only Stats fields not indexed

Comment: Please see my schema
There are tables indexes - http://imgur.com/a/hrcnm , 
There are table structure - http://imgur.com/a/QXXL3 , 
There are admin panel - where i have to show results with all group by parameters - http://imgur.com/a/5czjZ

Comment: This is simple query - http://imgur.com/a/eEbAp | 
mysql> select sum(requests) from Stats;  | result 1 row in set (4.53 sec)